# C# char.isupper throwing error when a number is put in string index

Tags: c#, passwords

I'm trying to make a password validator but this code throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when I input a number:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Password
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            string password = textBox1.Text;
            if (password.All(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)))
            {
                button4.Text = "✓";
                button4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                button4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                if (password.Length >= 3 && password.Length <= 8)
                {
                    button1.Text = "✓";
                    button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                    button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                    if (password.Any(char.IsDigit))
                    {
                        button2.Text = "✓";
                        button2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                        button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        // Error thrown below when I input a number
                        if (char.IsUpper(password[0]) && (char.IsLower(password[8])))
                        {
                            label1.Text = "   Valid";
                            label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            button3.Text = "✓";
                            button3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            label1.Text = " Invalid";
                            label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                            button2.Text = "✖";
                            button2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label1.Text = " Invalid";
                        label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                        button3.Text = "✖";
                        button3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                        button3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = " Invalid";
                    label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                    button1.Text = "✖";
                    button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                    button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                button4.Text = "✖";
                button4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                button4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share more detail about your code? Where did you define `password` variable? Where it is coming from?

Comment: not reproduceable https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ki2Zql

Comment: Is your input string at least 9 chars long? Else you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when trying to access `password[8]`

Comment: What is the error you get and which line throw it?

Comment: @Rafalon that is the exception that i am getting (the password must be 3-8 letters long) can you please elaborate on what that error means,i dont understand it

Comment: @LeviathanCo see my answer below

Comment: Please click "Copy details" on the dialog that shows when your code breaks on the exception and include this with your question. It seems unlikely the code you've provided can throw any exception other than `IndexOutOfRangeException` as Rafalon suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you can see why you are having this problem, relevant parts of your code:

- You check that your password is strictly shorter than 9 characters:

```
    if (password.Length >= 3 && password.Length <= 8)
    {
```

- You check that your password contains a number:

```
        if (password.Any(char.IsDigit))
        {
```

- You try to access `password[8]` which **can't** be accessed (as it is the 9th character, `password[0]` being the first character), hence your exception:

```
            if (char.IsUpper(password[0]) && (char.IsLower(password[8])))
            {
```

### In short:

You are getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` because you are trying to access the 9th character of a string which only contains 3 to 8 characters. (the 3rd `if`)
You are only getting this exception when your input contains a digit because you only try to access the 9th character when your input contains a digit. (the 2nd `if`)

---

If you need to check the last character of a string that can vary in length, don't hardcode the index like you did.
You can use `password[password.Length-1]` to get the last character.

Comment: yes but, it only happens when i input a number on the string

Comment: Because you only enter this if `password.Any(char.IsDigit)` (the second `if` in this code sample)

Comment: so how do i fix this?

Comment: Why do you need to check anything about the 9th character of a 3 to 8 character long string?

Comment: ok so i changed the 8 to a 7

Comment: This will still throw an exception if your input length is 7 or less. What exactly is your requirement? Does the last character need to be lower?

Comment: yes, the first letter should be capitalized, and the last be lowercase, sorry i did not clarify

Comment: See the last part of my updated answer (don't hardcode the index, you need the last character then use a formula that gives you the last character)